# How do I set option 119 in systemd-network [DHCPServer]?

Tags: systemd, dhcp, systemd-networkd

I've tried, among other things:

`SendOption=119:string:example.com`

tcpdump says "malformed packet"

```
0000   64 4b f0 1a 05 9a 00 e0 67 26 5b 13 08 00 45 c0   dK......g&[...E.
0010   01 50 00 00 00 00 40 11 52 ca c0 a8 52 01 c0 a8   .P....@.R...R...
0020   52 c1 00 43 00 44 01 3c 5d 42 02 01 06 00 fc 45   R..C.D.<]B.....E
0030   70 21 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 c0 a8 52 c1 00 00   p!..........R...
0040   00 00 00 00 00 00 64 4b f0 1a 05 9a 00 00 00 00   ......dK........
0050   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
0060   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
0070   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
0080   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
0090   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
00a0   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
00b0   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
00c0   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
00d0   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
00e0   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
00f0   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
0100   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
0110   00 00 00 00 00 00 63 82 53 63 35 01 05 33 04 00   ......c.Sc5..3..
0120   00 1c 20 01 04 ff ff ff 00 03 04 c0 a8 52 01 06   .. ..........R..
0130   04 c0 a8 52 01 65 13 41 6d 65 72 69 63 61 2f 4c   ...R.e.America/L
0140   6f 73 5f 41 6e 67 65 6c 65 73 77 0b 65 78 61 6d   os_Angelesw.exam
0150   70 6c 65 2e 63 6f 6d 36 04 c0 a8 52 01 ff         ple.com6...R..
```

---

`SendOption=119:uint16:056269726368046172706100`

tcpdump says it's not receiving option 119

---

I used https://jjjordan.github.io/dhcp119/ to guess at other encodings.

```
systemctl --version
systemd 247 (247.3-7)
```

Comment: It's not a string, it's a hex encode. See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3397 for details on how it's constructed.

Comment: Glad I figured that out only to relearn that search domains are busted on macos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SendOption=119:string:\x07example\x03com\x00`

You can use the generator at
https://jjjordan.github.io/dhcp119/

to get close and then edit it do what systemd wants.